# How to connect npm with NuGet packages?

Tags: npm, nuget, fable-f#

I've started a Fable project using a starter template. In order to run it, I was previous successfully using `npm run build`.

Using Visual Studio, I installed some NuGet packages (Serilog, Dapper) but now when I call npm start, the terminal complains that the NuGet packages calls cannot be resolved:

```
ERROR in ./src/Project.App/App.fs
Module Error (from ./node_modules/fable-loader/index.js):
C:/Users/markr/git-repos/SampleProject/src/SampleProject.App/App.fs(95,12): (95,47) error FABLE: Cannot resolve Serilog.Log.Error
 @ ./src/SampleProject.App/SampleProject.App.fsproj 1:0-25 1:0-25
```

It makes this same complaint for all NuGet package calls. How do I make it so that I can run `npm run build` while using NuGet packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out what I'm trying to do is impossible. Using SAFE architecture now to be able to properly implement a NuGet side (server) and an npm side (client)